# MYSQL DateTime Now()+5 days/hours/minutes/seconds?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am looking for a way to when inserting into mysql using now() to modify the datetime.

eg

`update`users`set`expires`= NOW()+5days where...`

Comment: Are you inserting or updating?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
update users set expires=  NOW() + interval 5 day where ...;
```